# RSPEC testing controller rendering view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, controller

So I am pretty new to testing with RSPEC

I am just testing the rendering of my controller like so:

```
describe "GET job" do 
  it "renders the jobs view" do 
  get :jobs
  expect(response).to render_template :jobs
end
```

However my view (jobs) is a folder, not a template so the above dosnt work. How do i test to see if the response is going to the jobs view folder. inside my jobs view folder i have many different files.

My customer controller action looks like so:

```
 def jobs
    @jobs = @customer.jobs
 end
```

Comment: Which template in the folder is the one that should be rendered by the jobs action?

Comment: render_template("jobs/foobar")

Answer (score 4):

To test that the template `foobar` inside `app/views/jobs/` is rendered you should use this code:

```
describe "GET job" do 
  it "renders the jobs view" do 
  get :jobs
  expect(response).to render_template :foobar
end
```

If you are not testing `JobsController` and would like to make sure that it still renders `app/views/jobs/foobar` then you should change it to this line:

```
expect(response).to render_template("jobs/foobar")
```

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, in rspec controller test view rendering has been stubbed by default. To check view rendering in controller specs you have to do as follows:

```
describe "GET job" do 
  render_views

  it "renders the jobs view" do 
  get :jobs

  expect(response).to render_template("jobs/foobar")
end
```

where `render_views` will make render respective views of a controller action.

Comment: Does this convert it into a request spec? I did this and it goes from 200ms to 7000ms to run that one test